# Faster Numpy: Contiguous Number Replacement

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone help me make this faster?

```
import numpy as np

# an array to split
a = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1])

# idx where the number changes
idx = np.where(np.roll(a,1)!=a)[0][1:]

# split of array into groups
aout = np.split(a,idx)

# sum of each group
sumseg = [aa.sum() for aa in aout]

#fill criteria
idx2 = np.where( (np.array(sumseg)>0) & (np.array(sumseg)<2) )

#fill targets
[aout[ai].fill(0) for ai in idx2[0]]

# a is now updated? didn't follow how a gets updated
# return a
```

I noticed that `a` gets updated through this process, but didn't understand how those objects remained link thought the splitting etc...

If it is important, or helps, `a` is actually a 2d array and I am looping over each row/column performing this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Better solution 1D:**

We can use a convolution:

```
aout = ((np.convolve(a,[1,1,1],mode='same')>1)&(a>0)).astype(a.dtype)
# aout = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

**Better solution 2D:**

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

aout = ((convolve2d(a,np.ones((1,3)),mode='same')>1)&(a>0)).astype(a.dtype)

#aout = array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

**Why `a` changed ?**

And to understand why `a` is updated in your process, you need to understand the difference between a copy and a view.

From the documentation:

> **View**
>
> It is possible to access the array differently by just changing
> certain metadata like stride and dtype without changing the data
> buffer. This creates a new way of looking at the data and these new
> arrays are called views. The data buffer remains the same, so any
> changes made to a view reflects in the original copy. A view can be
> forced through the ndarray.view method.
>
> **Copy**
>
> When a new array is created by duplicating the data buffer as
> well as the metadata, it is called a copy. Changes made to the copy do
> not reflect on the original array. Making a copy is slower and
> memory-consuming but sometimes necessary. A copy can be forced by
> using ndarray.copy.

Or `np.split()` return a view not a copy of `a`, so `aout` is still pointing to the same data buffer as `a`, if you change `aout` you change `a`.

**Benchmarking**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,2,(1000000,))

def continuous_split(a):
    idx = np.where(np.roll(a,1)!=a)[0][1:]
    aout = np.split(a,idx)
    sumseg = [aa.sum() for aa in aout]
    idx2 = np.where( (np.array(sumseg)>0) & (np.array(sumseg)<2) )
    [aout[ai].fill(0) for ai in idx2[0]]
    return aout
    
def continuous_conv(a):
    return ((np.convolve(a,[1,1,1],mode='same')>1)&(a>0)).astype(a.dtype)

%timeit continuous_split(a)
%timeit continuous_conv(a)
```

*np.split() solution:*

```
668 ms ± 11.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*np.convolve() solution:*

```
7.63 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This there a way to make this work for unknown lengths of contiguous numbers? In the example we have ```idx2 = np.where( (np.array(sumseg)>0) & (np.array(sumseg)<2) )``` so how can the ```0``` and the ```2``` be parameterized using convolution?